Colour the vertices of a polygon
What is the smallest polygon whose vertices can be coloured with 6 colours such that any two colours are adjacent somewhere in the polygon?
Just to clarify: the colouring should be such that every colour should be adjacent to every other colour in the polygon.
Source: inspired by a question on math.SE

Is it required for a color to be adjacent to itself?  I.e. are two adjacent edges of the same color required?

@FlorianF. In the clarification, I said “every colour should be adjacent to every other colour”. Two same colours may or may not be adjacent.


 Each color needs to be adjacent to 5 other unique colors. Each vertex is adjacent to 2 other vertices, so each color must be included at least 3 times. This means the minimum possible is an 18-gon; here's an example coloring:


 


Could you explain how you obtained the colouring?

@Pranay Honestly, just trial and error. There's a lot of leeway.

@Pranay Note that there are only 6*5/2=15 color pairings that need to be used, so on the 18-gon you have 3 free bonds left over. Enough to quickly find some solution with trial and error.

@quarague. I understand. I was hoping that someone would answer the general case with $k$ colours as well. I have an answer for this too, and of course you can’t use trial and error for that

General solution for k colors:

 if k is odd, $k*(k-1)/2$.  If k is even, $k*k/2$.

Proof:

 Consider a complete graph with k vertices, with each vertex corresponding to one color.  A coloring of the polygon's will correspond to a circuit of the graph which uses every edge at least once.  This circuit takes a minimum edge trips $ N(edges in graph) + N(odd vertices in graph)/2 $ (see Euler circuits).  Choosing a partition of the vertices into pairs and adding an extra edge for each of those pairs will create a graph with all even degrees showing this bound is attainable.


 If k is odd, every vertex is even, so it will be $k*(k-1)/2$.  If k is even, every vertex is odd, so it will be $k(k-1)/2 + k/2$ = $(kk-k)/2 + k/2$ = $kk/2$


Great answer! You can also show that this is the best you can do for both $k$ odd (obvious) and even (almost obvious).
